# Masking domain using htaccess wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Two websites, both WordPress installations.

Old Website is hosted with provider A with their real domain - website.com.au (not real address obviously)

New Website is hosted with provider B and has temporary domain - lotsofcrazynumbers.com.au

In the process of transferring domain over to provider B but they can't wait for that to happen and have asked me to fwd their real domain over to New Website.

So I edited .htaccess in Old Website's admin area to fwd to New Website's temporary domain but of course the temporary domain is displaying, which will freak out their customers.

I used the following in the .htaccess

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "lotsofcrazynumbers.com.au" [R=301,L]

I know that I probably haven't set this up right but domains and DNS is not really my thing.  Is there anyway that I can mask the temporary domain so that it looks like their normal domain until the domain transfer has been finalised?

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: You should either redirect using the A record in your DNS, or you can use an HTML frame to embed the web site at the temporary domain... See http://www.maxum.com/Rumpus/Blog/URLCloaking.html

Comment: i tried to edit the DNS where the domain is registered with the temporary domains A record but it wouldn't let me save the new record.  I didn't want to start deleting too many records so I thought that just forwarding domain to the temporary domain would suffice for a few days whilst the transfer happens.

Comment: Plus the new website is hosted on the temporary domain so embedding it won't work.  I want the existing domain to be shown when browsing the new site with the temporary domain.  Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite's [P]roxy option might work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://lotsofcrazynumbers.com.au$1" [P,L]
```

Set the above in the .htaccess file of Old Website, and it should proxy any requests to New Website without change the URL in the browser.

Make sure to test properly though. :-)

Comment: Thanks Aubrey, I have applied that and will let you know how it goes.  Cheers.. brett

Comment: Nope, no good.. That keeps the URL but doesn't fwd the Old Site to the New Site :( I'm gonna keep hunting for a solution.. thanks for the suggestion.